# How to set the DHCP server IP address to windows 7 client

Tags: dhcp

I configured a windows 2012 server inside virtual machine in Ubuntu 14.04.
I installed DHCP, DNS, AD.

I want to setup client's to use my DHCP server instead of Routers.

1) Now how can I assign my server's Ip address to WIndows 7, which is in another VM in the same Ubuntu host?

I know how to setup DNS server's address in client PC. 
 But How do we do it for DHCP?

2) Is it possible to access my DHCP server which is in VM by Other machines on the same network ? How?

info:

```
 windows 2012 VM IP: 192.168.247.201

 Linux Host ip     : 192.168.0.102
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer... the DHCP server who replies first to the DHCPDISCOVER wins.

Long Answer...

DHCP utilizes **broadcast** for communication between client and server.

1. Client initiates the process by sending a **DHCPDISCOVER** frame.
2. Server receives the frame and sends back a **DHCPOFFER** (=network configuration settings for client)
3. Client sends a **DHCPREQUEST** frame to the server to request the address slot it got via the DHCPOFFER frame
4. Server sends a  **DHCPACK** to acknowledge the request
5. Client assigns the ip address settings

In case there are multiple dhcp servers the one who responds first wins. If a client already received a DHCPOFFER it will still send back a DHCPREQUEST to decline the offer.

To workaround your issue I would recommend using a Host-Only or NAT network adapter to isolate your lab environment from your network.

Comment: I disabled router DHCP server.Both win7 and windows Server 2012 are in NAT.    But win7 doesn't get IP from my server.  I don't see any machine name under "Address Leases" option in DHCP server. Is there any setting i missed?

Comment: The problem is that your server is within a different network segment than your PCs physical NIC.

To make it clearer...You have two NICs on your PC 

NIC1 is within your local area network (e.g. 192.168.0.0/24)
NIC2 is within your NAT network (192.168.100.0/24)

Your DHCP server is within your NAT network. If a PC in 192.168.0.0/24 sends a DHCPDISCOVER there is no server to answer because your DHCP server VM is located within the NAT network and broadcast does not traverse from 192.168.0.0/24 to your NAT network 192.168.100.0

Hope it is clear... p.s. vote up if answers are helpful

Comment: 1) So your are saying I can't use DHCP server in a VM to supply IP addresses to my network?   2) I have a windows 7 machine that is also in VM in same host . Both are in NAT. So win7 is able to use my DHCP server. Am I right? Can you please tell me the settings? I can ping between win7 and win server.

Comment: Yes you can use your DHCP server with your Windows 7 VM. 
You could also use your DHCP server for your "real" network if you were doing bridging in your virtualization tool (e.g. VMware Workstation).

If you could tell me which tool you are using for virtualization I could point you into the rigth direction..

Comment: Am using:    VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64 .

Comment: Ok - I see the issue... VMware Player can only do NAT as network option.
If you want to have your VMs directly in your network you would need to do bridging as said before. VMware Workstation and Oracle VirtualBox will support this feature... p.s. VirtualBox is free.

Comment: 1) Right now please tell me get Ip to windows 7 VM which is in same host in   NAT as network option?    2) If I use Vmware workstation what would be the settings? please help me.

Comment: 1) Right now please tell me get Ip to windows 7 VM which is in same host in NAT as network option?

What do you mean. I do not understand the question.

2) 

2.1. Import your VMs from VMware Player --> 
Right Click in Library pane and select 'Open', navigate to your virtual machine path and select the .vmx File of your virtual machine

2.2. Edit Virtual Machine Settings and set network connection to bridged
Virtual Machine Settings > Network Adapter > Bridged

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30113/discussion-between-melvin-and-kaisero).

Answer (score 1):

**About DHCP:**
Any machine without a static IP will send out a Broadcast packet requesting an IP from any DHCP servers on the network. The client doesn't need the server IP. If DHCP is setup correctly (and your VM's are networked properly) it will work automatically.

Scroll down to *Operation* on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) to see the request process.

**About IP's:**
A DHCP server should have a static IP in the range it is handing out. If server IP is 192.168.247.201, then it should hand out 192.168.247.X addresses, or change the netmask to allow variation in the 3rd octet.

**About VM's**
If you follow those steps, then a good method of testing is isolating the VM's from the physical network. While they are Host-only they can only talk to each other (and the host machine). Like being on a switched network.

If you use NAT, then your NIC acts like a router, allowing talk between subnets. Bridged mode allows your VM's to act like machines that are on the network directly, like another PC in the home/office.

Comment: I disabled router DHCP server.Both win7 and windows Server 2012 are in NAT.    But win7 doesn't get IP from my server.  I don't see any machine name under "Address Leases" option in DHCP server. Is there any setting i missed?

Comment: my server has static IP: 192.168.247.201. I changed win7 to HOST-Only. ip: 172.16.54.130. ping worked for server-> win7, but failed for win7->server. I changed myserver to Host-Only, but doesn't get IP for server, even if i changed to dynamic Ip. when i do: ipconfig /release; ipconfig /renew; -> Shows the error : "The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation." I changed both to NAT. Now both ping works!...

Comment: no. Netmask of server which I have set manually is:  255.255.255.0.   For win7 it is getting automatically and that is also same: 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Then whether you use static or DHCP your client needs to use a 192.168.247.X address to be able to talk to the server without a router. While the client has no IP it should still be able to request it, once it has it though, pinging won't work without the router. (Which is your network card doing NAT in this case.)

Comment: Host Ip is : 192.168.0.102. But VM's ip start with 192.168.247.  My Subnet mask of win server is: 255.255.255.0.
Does it make any probs?   One more thing my lease time is 24 hours so if disable DHCP server in ROUTER it gets the same IP again. How can I overcome it and force win7 to broadcast a DHCP request?

Comment: Use <code>ipconfig /release</code> in command prompt. The rest sounds ok. If you have any more issues, please open a new question. Good luck.